# How to setup Project Backlog in TFS pro grammatically?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, tfs

I have look around the other post about this Project Backlog, but i want to those missing field in this image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxXHN.png)

I need those missing fields like workitem, Title, Assigned To, State, Effort, Business.

I have this code with me right now.

```
/ Set up default team sprint date and time
        var teamConfig = _tfs.GetService<TeamSettingsConfigurationService>();
        var css = _tfs.GetService<ICommonStructureService4>();

        string rootNodePath = string.Format("\\{0}\\Iteration\\Release 1\\Sprint 1", _selectedTeamProject.Name);
        var pathRoot = css.GetNodeFromPath(rootNodePath);

        css.SetIterationDates(pathRoot.Uri, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5), DateTime.Now.AddDays(7));

        var configs = teamConfig.GetTeamConfigurationsForUser(new[] { _selectedTeamProject.Uri });
        var team = configs.Where(c => c.TeamName == "Demo").FirstOrDefault();

        var ts = team.TeamSettings;
        ts.BacklogIterationPath = string.Format(@"{0}\Release 1", _selectedTeamProject.Name);
        ts.IterationPaths = new string[] { string.Format(@"{0}\Release 1\Sprint 1", _selectedTeamProject.Name), string.Format(@"{0}\Release 1\Sprint 2", _selectedTeamProject.Name) };

        var tfv = new TeamFieldValue();
        tfv.IncludeChildren = true;
        tfv.Value = _selectedTeamProject.Name;
        ts.TeamFieldValues = new []{tfv};

        teamConfig.SetTeamSettings(team.TeamId, ts);
```

Comment: What's your finally purpose? Do you need the value of the fields or just fields? Besides, which one are you actually talking about, Project Backlog or Product Backlog? According to your screenshot, looks like you are point to the product backlog.

Comment: Yup Product Backlog, i need to rebuild the webparts because TFS 2018 has disabled it, therefore, i need to code the product backlog to have those column field shown in the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your screenshot, seems you are using the **Work item Summary** web part. After the upgrade to TFS2018, your TFS SharePoint sites will display, but all integration functionality is disabled.

[image]

The official recommended  way is using [TFS Dashboards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/dashboards/) for a better way to create dashboards. From that it's more easy to track/display the fields in a work item.

You could directly use some 3-party  Work Item widget such as [this one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JuanDelMoral.vsts-extensions-workItemWidget#overview) which also provides a summary for a selected work item.

To get or update work items such as product backlog fields  pro grammatically, you could use Rest API-- **[Get a list of work items](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#get-a-list-of-work-items)** to handle this. It will also return all related fields name and value. Which also include a [*C# (GetWorkItemsByIDs method)*](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-dotnet-samples/blob/master/ClientLibrary/Snippets/Microsoft.TeamServices.Samples.Client/WorkItemTracking/WorkItemsSample.cs#L20) sample code.  About how to customize a dashboard in sharepoint, please take a look at this [thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/sharepoint-dashboards/project-portal-dashboards#Customizing).

Comment: Hi Patrick, just to confirm, i have to create a dashboard from the GUI, and  code it out to query the work items or other columns fields right?

Comment: @TheWay Yes, there are multiple tutorials in the web of this area. Such as [Add a dashboard widget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/add-dashboard-widget) Please take a look at it.